# DataBinding: 'System.Web.UI.Pair' does not contain a property with the name 'First'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, drop-down-menu

I'm data binding a list of pairs to a drop down list, for some reason it's not working and I'm intrigued.

The code I am using is :

```
public void BindDropDown(List<Pair> dataList)
{
    ddlGraphType.DataTextField = "First";
    ddlGraphType.DataValueField = "Second";

    ddlGraphType.DataSource = dataList;
    ddlGraphType.DataBind();
}
```

I'm getting this exception, which is a lie!

```
DataBinding: 'System.Web.UI.Pair' does not contain a property with the name 'First'.
```

Thanks in advance.

**Added**

I know what the exception means, but a pair object does contain the First and Second properties, that's where the problem lies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`First` and `Second` are Fields not properties of `Pair` type. You need to create a class with two properties:

```
 public class NewPair
 {
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Second { get; set; }
 }
```

EDIT: Use of [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) : suggested by @Damien_The_Unbeliever & @Chris Chilvers

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> list = new List<Tuple<string, string>>()
 {
   new Tuple<string,string>("One","1"),
   new Tuple<string,string>("Two","2"),
};

ddlGraphType.DataTextField = "Item1";
ddlGraphType.DataValueField = "Item2";

ddlGraphType.DataSource = list;
ddlGraphType.DataBind();
```

Comment: Alternatively, in .net 4 you can use Tuple<string, string>

Comment: For .NET 4 or later, `Tuple<T1,T2>` might be a suitable replacement - it does implement properties rather than fields.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever & Chris Chilvers Thanks buddy! I appreciate your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Theat means the target property must be a dependency property. This also means that you cannot bind a field and Pair.First is field not **property**

Answer (score 0):

```
public sealed class Pair
{
}
```

Fields:

```
Public field    First   Gets or sets the first object of the object pair.
Public field    Second  Gets or sets the second object of the object pair.
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pair.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've forgot the `{get; set;}` after declaring the properties.

```
public class A
{

  //This is not a property
  public string Str;

 //This is a property
  public string Str2 {get; set;}

}
```